# Tab Bar Item Image Does Not Show Up

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard

I'm trying to assign a custom image to UITabBarItem in storyboard. Unfortunately, it shows me an box instead of an image.

Here's my PNG image
[image]

Storyboard:
[image]

How it appear in simulator:
[image]

Comment: You should use flat icons. XCode autofill it to default tint color, so its show your icon.

Comment: Is it possible to show image as it is?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Read the document called "Tab Bars" that's linked to at the top of the UITabBar class reference.

Comment: Well, this one? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UITabBar

Comment: Do I need to set an image property of UITabBarItem?

Answer (score 6):

As it turned out in order do display an actual image following code should be executed.

```
[self.activityItem setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"activity.png"] 
    imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Note the Rendering Mode of UIImage. You can find more about it [UITabBar Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UITabBar) Thanks to [@  Vladislav Kovalyov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2382397/vladislav-kovalyov)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Assets folder. Select your tab image. On the right side under Attributes you will find "Render As". Select "Original Image".